# ValueError: Found two metrics with the same name: recall

Tags: keras

I'm training a detection model where train and test data are 3D NumPy array. When start train this model found this type of error. Code link is given below

[Training_model.py](https://pastebin.com/jrb0R8ii)

[detection.py](https://pastebin.com/CKjnyJvr)

[perform_learning.py](https://pastebin.com/awki23XM)

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                        validation_data=validation_generator,
                        use_multiprocessing=True,
                        workers=6,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        callbacks=[checkpoint, tensorboard])
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/content/SpineFinder-master/train_detection_model.py", line 25, in 
shuffle=True)

File "/content/SpineFinder-master/learning_functions/perform_learning.py", line 57, in perform_learning
callbacks=[checkpoint, tensorboard])

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1479, in fit_generator
initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 848, in fit
tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 580, in **call**
result = self._call(*args, **kwds)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 627, in _call
self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 506, in _initialize
*args, **kwds))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2446, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2777, in _maybe_define_function
graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2667, in _create_graph_function
capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 981, in func_graph_from_py_func
func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 441, in wrapped_fn
return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 968, in wrapper
raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)

ValueError: in user code:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:543 train_step  **
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:391 update_state
    self._build(y_pred, y_true)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:333 _build
    self._set_metric_names()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:353 _set_metric_names
    m._name))
```

ValueError: Found two metrics with the same name: recall

Comment: Please include some more code, as there is little context as to what those variables represent.

Comment: which version of keras do you use?

Comment: Keras version - 2.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error stems from the following in detection.py:

```
    recall_background = km.binary_recall(label=0)
    recall_vertebrae = km.binary_recall(label=1)
```

According to [1] and [2], km.binary_recall() instantiates the keras.metrics.recall() class.  However, without the `name` kwarg, both lines uses the same name `recall`.   Therefore, in order to avoid this, it's my understanding that you'd have to specify the `name` kwarg like so:

```
    recall_background = km.binary_recall(name="recall_background", label=0)
    recall_vertebrae = km.binary_recall(name="recall_vertebrae", label=1)
```

[1] - [https://github.com/netrack/keras-metrics/blob/master/keras_metrics/\_\_init__.py#L34](https://github.com/netrack/keras-metrics/blob/master/keras_metrics/%5C_%5C_init__.py#L34)

[2] - https://github.com/netrack/keras-metrics/blob/master/keras_metrics/metrics.py#L150